# Error al autenticar una aplicación ASP.NET Core en el registro de aplicaciones de Azure para el desarrollo local

Tags: azure, autenticación, desarrollo

He configurado una aplicación en el registro de aplicaciones de Azure para el desarrollo local con ASP.NET Core. He creado un nuevo objeto en el registro de aplicaciones, también asigné roles a un grupo de Microsoft Entra ID (Colaborador de datos de Storage Blob  y  Lector de datos de Storage Blob).

Visual Studio está autenticado con una cuenta de usuario presente en Azure y miembro del grupo configurado en Entra ID.

Configuré la aplicación de la siguiente manera:

Esta es la configuración de launchSettings.json que

```
  "https": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002;http://localhost:5194",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
      "AZURE_CLIENT_ID": "XXXd69ed-dba5-4104-a413-f46428ffd7c0",
      "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "XXX25413-6329-41fb-923d-4f70372f072a",
      "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "XXXMisecretoxxxxxxx"

    }
  },
```

El program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAzureClients(x =>
{
    x.AddBlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://miblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net"));      
    x.UseCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
});
```

Inyección de dependencia en el controlador:

```
private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db, BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient )
 {
     _db = db;    
     _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
 }
```

Acción de controlador

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Get([FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
{
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("demoblob");
    var results = new List<string>();

    await foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
    {
        results.Add(blob.Name);
    }

    results.ToArray();
}
```

Tras ejecutar la aplicación presenta un error en el método Get, línea siguiente:

```
await foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
```

Descripción de error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:bb46c0f5-101e-0069-7ea9-831293000000
Time:2024-03-31T20:27:18.1148480Z
      Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
      ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

      Content:
      ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:bb46c0f5-101e-0069-7ea9-831293000000
Time:2024-03-31T20:27:18.1148480Z</Message></Error>
```

Al parecer hay algo que impide que se complete la autenticación en Azure, seguí esta documentación:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication/local-development-service-principal?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Ccommand-line

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication/local-development-dev-accounts?tabs=azure-portal%2Csign-in-visual-studio%2Ccommand-line